# Joomla myBlog template

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-template

I would like to edit my current template in myBlog component which I believe is located here:

```
\components\com_myblog\templates\bluestyle
```

My main reason for asking is because I don't know where to fix a misalignment in the website I am maintaining.

But if you would try to browse the other tabs on top of the site, they have no problems at all, it's just so happened that myBlog component has its own template aside from the default Joomla template.

I believe the problem is somewhere in this path of my Joomla file:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\lopez-link\components\com_myblog\templates\bluesky
```

Obviously my chosen template is named "bluesky" inside this folder it has 3 html files (**bloginfo.tmpl.html**, **entry.tmpl.html** and **index.tmpl.html**) and a CSS file (**template_style**). I included below my index.tmpl.html code.

**index.tmpl.html**

```
<?php
if ($entry and is_array($entry) and count($entry) != 0)
{
    foreach ($entry as $e)
    {
        $date = strtotime($e['created']);
        $month_day = strftime("%b ", $date) . strftime("%d", $date);
        $year = strftime("%Y", $date);
        $month_day = i8n_date($month_day);
    ?>
 <div class="entryContent">
<div class="entry">
    <table class="entryTitle">
        <tr>
            <td class="my-dateCell">
                <div class="dateContainer">     
                    <div class="date">
                        <div class="month"><span><?php echo $month_day; ?></span></div>
                        <div class="year"><span><?php echo $year; ?></span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="my-titleCell">
                <div class="entry-title">
                    <h3><a href="<?php echo $e['permalink']; ?>"><?php echo $e['title']; ?></a></h3>
                    <p>_MB_POSTED_BY <a href="<?php echo $e['authorLink']; ?>"><?php echo $e['author']; ?></a> in <?php echo $e['categories']; ?></p>
                </div>
            </td>           
            <?php if(!empty($e['avatar'])){ ?>
            <td class="my-avatarCell">
                <div class="userAvatar">
                <?php echo $e['avatar']; ?>
                </div>
            </td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
        if ($e['beforeContent'])
        { ?>
        <div class="onBeforePrepareContent">
            <?php echo $e['beforeContent'];?>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    <div class="entry-body"> 
        <?php echo $e['text']; ?>
        <div class="clear"></div> 
    </div>
    <?php if ($e['afterContent'])
        { ?>
        <div class="onAfterPrepareContent">
            <?php echo $e['afterContent'];?>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    <div class="entry-footer">
        <?php
            if ($e['comments']!="") // if comments enabled

                echo '<div class="entry-comment"><a href="'.$e['permalink'].'#comments">'.$e['comments'] .'</a>';
            else
                echo '<div>';
            if ($e['comments']!="" and $e['readmore']=="1")
                 echo ' | ';
        ?>
        <?php  // IF NEED READMORE
        if ($e['readmore']=="1")
        { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $e['permalink']; ?><?php echo $showAnchor; ?>">_MB_READ_MORE...</a>
        <?php } ?>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
 <?php
}
   }
 ?>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED :
May this help you.
find the code

```
if ($e['readmore']=="1")
{ ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $e['permalink']; ?><?php echo $showAnchor; ?>">_MB_READ_MORE...</a>
        <?php }
```

and replace it with

```
if ($e['readmore']=="1")
        { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $e['permalink']; ?><?php echo $showAnchor; ?>">_MB_READ_MORE...</a>
        <?php } 
        echo '</div>';
```

Comment: i just wanna ask sir, are you referring to the "\components\com_myblog\templates\bluestyle\index.tmpl.html" ? coz i don't see any missing </div>? on it. please guide me more.. thnx

Comment: Its difficult make any guesses from here. Let ma know where can I find this component.

Comment: sir i edit my previous question and included the html code which i have a strong feeling that causes the problem. The name of my joomla template is "gk_thenews2" and the for myBlog i dont know what version this is.. how do i find its version? thank you

Comment: then it will not be possible to give any solution until have the components(you are using).

Comment: you were right... i did a deliberate finding on were to put your "echo '</div>'" and atlast it fix my problem..so thanks for the help.. Godbless